# Quick 64bit integer ID Lookup/Search

Tags: c++, search, dictionary, lookup

I'm working on a game, and to be on the safe side any user (programmer) is only allowed to store IDs to objects instead of pointers, and must use this ID to get the pointer to the object in order to have to some quality alone-time with it.

Let's use the worst case scenario: Every single ID is in use. It is 64 bit so there ya go: 18446744073709551616 IDs to search through. A lot of the data is stored in a database, and our program lookup either returns a pointer, or a null pointer. A null pointer means the program must access the database in order to load the object, after which it will have a pointer.

**Ideas:**
So the only real trick I know here is binary search. So in the worst case that means 64 comparisons for every ID lookup.

Another idea I had was creating a static space partition, a tree where every branch splits up into a power of 2 amount of branches, but only until a reasonable depth. Using a bitwise operator on the ID instead of the modulus operator to find out what branch it belongs to on every level. Every possible branch in the tree always exists, but at some depth they stop and a binary search is still required because the exact number of values is still unknown.

What are your ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical case for a hash map. First, realize how many IDs you can actually have active at any one time. 2^64 is nonsense since then even the data structure just to hold these IDs and the pointers to the objects would already be at least 268'435'456 TB. Now, there's nothing wrong with using 64bit IDs, but figure out how many objects you will have active at any one time, choose a reasonable number like say 5'000 and use a hash map of say 10 times the number of objects. If your load factor is low enough and your hash function good enough you will get an amortized O(1) access time.

Comment: Yes, now I see how stupid my idea was: Perhaps the ID space allows for 2^64 possibilities, but all the objects would never all be loaded into the memory any way. Thanks, and, I feel a bit ashamed now ;(, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the number of active objects would be much larger, say 1 million, you can still use a relatively small hash map, for example a map of size 10000. Each element of the map points to a linked list of IDs. These lists are searched using simple linear searrch. If the hash function is well chosen, the IDs will be distributed evenly (or close to that) over the 10000 entries in the hash map. Thus each entry of the hash table will contain about 100 IDs. Linear searching such a list takes 50 comparisona on average.

In one of my apps the number of symbols was around 1000. I used just simple linear search. Performance analysis showed that 90% of CPU time was spent in the table lookup. Next I made a hash table of just 32 entries -> CPU load of the table lookup dropped to below 4%. Problem solved. Enlarging the hash table would have no noticeable impact on speed (less than 4%) so I left it at the size of 32.

Conclusion: you can use a hash table that is smaller than the number of elements. This requires an average number of comparisons of (Total number of IDs / size of hash table / 2) Choose the hash table size large enough to reduce CPU time for table lookup to a low fraction of total CPU time.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a good solution under higher load factors. It should be noted though that the linked list imposes an extra level of indirection and thus more cache misses. It's a balance between available memory and performance requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> "What are your ideas?"

I'd use `std::map` first and only think about implementing my own solution if the performance sucked.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/